# Make radiobutton icon smaller

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I use this to customize RadioButtons:

```
<!-- Radio button style -->
<style name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/checkbox_unchecked</item>
</style>
```

But the image `@drawable/checkbox_unchecked` is very big.

**Do you know how can I make it smaller?**

Comment: you could reduce the size of the image - this would also reduce the size of your application, which is always good.

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb Thanks for your comment. Which is a suitable size for the icon?

Comment: I´d try with 100x100 px and reduce it further if necessary - if your RadioButton has a fixed size, you can also scale it down and change the size in your code. (still, dont use too big files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you can achieve what you want by ***reducing the size of your image***. But I would recommend using the following code. This will help you set images for both the **unselected** and **selected** modes.

This is how you can achieve it, in a few steps:
-Create `Image Drawables` for their two states (checked/unchecked).
-Create selector for this two drawables. The sample content should be something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
</selector>
```

-Add this selector as a `android:button` attribute to `RadioButton`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="Custom RadioButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```